# Ember-data loading async and order results according with property

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, ember-data

I'm learning about ember/ember-data and would like to fetch some data from server and order it.

My json data is something like

```
{
  'ninjas': [
    { id: '1', name: 'Ninja 1', age: 23},
    { id: '2', name: 'Ninja 2', age: 27},
    { id: '3', name: 'Ninja 3', age: 22}
  ],
  'clans': [
    { id: '1566', title: 'Foot Clan', ninja_ids: ['1', '2']},
    { id: '8941', title: 'Hand Clan', ninja_ids: ['3']}
  ]
}
```

The templates are

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="clans">
  <div>Clans</div>
  <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
      <li>
        {{#link-to 'clan' this}}{{title}}{{/link-to}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="clan">
  <div>{{title}}</div>

  {{#each fetchedNinjas}}
    <ul>
      <li>{{fetchedNinjas}}</li>
    </ul>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here is the basic App script:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.AplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({})
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('ninjas');
  this.resource('clans');
  this.resource('clan', {path: 'clans/:clan_id'});
});
```

The ninja script is here:

```
App.Ninja = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  age: DS.attr('number'),
  clans: DS.hasMany('clan')
});

App.NinjasRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params, transition, queryParams) {
    return this.store.find('ninja');
  }
});
```

Here is the Clan Model, ClansRoute, ClanRoute

```
App.Clan = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  ninjas: DS.hasMany('ninja', {async: true})
});

App.ClansRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params, transition, queryParams) {
    return this.store.find('clan');
  }
});

App.ClanRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params, transition, queryParams) {
    return this.store.find('clan', params.clan_id);
  }
});
```

I think that I should get the related ninja data on ClanController and then order it, but I don't know how to proceed.

```
App.ClanController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  fetchedNinjas: function () {
    //should I use a promise here?
  }.property('ninjas')
});
```

Comment: So what seems to be your problem here? Do you get the ninjas in the clan controller? Can you access them? Is your problem just on how to order the ninjas in the ClanController?

Comment: I would like to fetch the clan related ninjas asynchronously. So, everytime that the user clicks in a specific clan, I would like to get the ninjas and order they by age. I can't access the ninjas data yet (and according with dev tools, there's no request to the ninjas/id url on backend). I don't know where is the problem, if is on `.property('ninjas')` or the way I'm using fetchedNinjas.

Comment: Assuming you have set your backend properly for ember data, you should get a clan record each time you visit /clans/:id that has a ninja_ids array attribute. When calling clan.ninjas , it does not return an array with ninja objects though, but a promise that will give you the ninja objects when resolved. So in order to get the ninjas array in your clan controller you should do this.content.get('ninjas').then (function{... Also in the property you should set property('ninjas.@each') so it will be triggered each time you get a ninja.